# How can I extract details from credit card images using opencv-python?

Tags: image-processing, ocr, opencv, python

I want to perform credit card OCR using opencv-python. [sample credit card image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsARK.jpg) How can this be done?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: So far, I am able to detect the edges using Canny with some preprocessing using GaussianBlur and thresholding. However, since the corners are rounded, the contours dont seem to work. I also tried using Harris corner detection but not sure how to get co-ordinates of the corners using that. I want to crop the credit card out of the image and do 4 point perspective transform so that I can do template matching

Answer (score 1):

This is what is at the top of my head (a very high-level algorithm):

1. Detect the outline using blob detection (probably verify that you have two sets of parallel lines)
2. With the two sets of parallel lines, you know how the characters are aligned. Rotate the entire image in that angle, so text would be horizontal (which makes your work simpler)
3. Perform adaptive binary thresholding (eg. Otsu).
4. Usually, if you know approximately where to look for information (the co-ordinates relative to the card border), you can use any OCR algorithm when you segment text (binarize it).